# How to call a function in a function in React (auth, routing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, authentication, routes

I am trying to create a component that executes straight when DOM is loaded, onInit();

This function posts a token to an endpoint, then if successful, I am trying to run a function called 'valid()'

The problem I keep getting is, when I try to call the 'valid' function in response, it says cannot history of undefined.

I think I am not passing props in the right way.

Also if unsuccessful, an Error page should be returned.

Thanks for any help on this

```
export class LandingPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.valid = this.valid.bind(this);
    }

    valid = () => {
        auth.login(() => {
            this.props.history.push("/app");
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        onInit();

        function onInit(props) {

            const apiUrl = "www.somefakedomain.com/endpoint"

            axios
                .post(apiUrl, {
                    token: 'somevalue123'
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    //CALL VALID FUNCTION HERE
                    this.valid; //throws error, how to run function here
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    //Show Error Page
                });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Spinner />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not calling your function with arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing anything to your onInIt function.

Are you perhaps trying to do something like this? -

```
export class LandingPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.valid = this.valid.bind(this);
    }

    valid = () => {
        auth.login(() => {
            this.props.history.push("/app");
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        function onInit(props) {

            const apiUrl = "www.somefakedomain.com/endpoint"

            axios
                .post(apiUrl, {
                    token: 'somevalue123'
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    //CALL VALID FUNCTION HERE
                    this.valid(); //need to call function not reference it//throws error, how to run function here
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    //Show Error Page
                });
        }
      onInIt(this.props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Spinner />
        </div>
    );
}
}

javascript reactjs function authent
```